# Javascript onclick/onload cross domain tracker

Tags: javascript, function, events, cross-domain

I'm trying to build a 'function' tracker or something like that which sends a request to the server if the function is triggered.

I have just one problem, how to trigger the function on a button, which redirects to the other domain.

If I use the onclick='' the function is executed, but it doesn't have time to send(or get back) the request to server.

The main point would be to make it fire once the target url is loaded.

Is it possible to do so with Javascript? Something with target onload, set timeout somewhere, or if the target is loaded the execute this and that?
I've tried to do trigger it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
<a class="button" onclick="trackfunction();"  href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">click here to load it</a> 

<a class="button" onclick="setTimeout(function(){trackfunction()},0);"  href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">click here to load it</a>
```

Any other ideas are welcomed:)

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the javascript function first and do a redirection in the function itself.

```
function trackfunction() {
    /*
        Tracking code
    */

    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
}
```

Remove the href attribute from the  tag otherwise give href = "#".